# GNOME To Do doesn't sync with Google calendar anymore

Tags: gnome, sync, google-calendar

I've been using the GNOME To Do app on Ubuntu for a while now on several machines, and it worked without much effort.

However, recently I noticed that changes are not synced anymore. If I make a change in google calendar (add or move a task), it does not get added or moved in the To Do app. Vice versa: when I add or move a task to a later date in the To Do app, it does not update in google calendar. Also: when I reboot, the changes made in the To Do app appear to be gone.

I've tried looking for a manual update button in the app, but couldn't find it.

Anyone have any clues what might cause this?

Comment: Same here (except on ArchLinux) :-(

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It could be related to this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calendar/+bug/1866999 Also reported here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/-/issues/626